# Image height not working well on Safari while using CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, grid

Hi i am having some troubles while trying to "fit" an image inside a css grid container (The problem only happends while using Safari, Firefox and Chrome is ok.) Problem is, the img height while using Safari takes all the available space and this makes the image looks deformed (Below is the link to the screenshot I took)

These are the properties I am applying to the image:

```
img {
   flex-basis: calc(66.67% - 3.6rem);
   width: 66.67%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEWiM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You may try re-defining the height of the image as the same problem occurred with me and by re-defining, it worked for me on safari. And also instead of giving the width and height in percentage, give it in pixels as it will be more convenient.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me, I just specified the a max-width and a max-height for the image. The image has the shape of a square so by applying 47.2rem to both properties fixed it. I think it is something Apple should fix.